# How to install Mathoid for Mediawiki website?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am using a  t.2 micro instance in Amazon web services for my MediaWiki website https://mechwiki.ml. Installed by using bitnami.

I would like to write math equation in my wiki, so I installed Math extension. but "Test Rendering Presentation MathML sample failed" and "Test Checking if the link to SVG image is correct failed" error messages are showing in https://mechwiki.ml/wiki/Special:MathStatus.

In my localsettings.php my settings are

```
# Math Extension
wfLoadExtension( 'Math' );
$wgMathValidModes[] = 'mathml';
$wgDefaultUserOptions['math'] = 'mathml';
$wgMathMathMLUrl = 'https://mathoid-beta.wmflabs.org/';
$wgMathFullRestbaseURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_';
```

These above settings are from https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Math#Mathoid_as_a_service

After that, I found that I need to install my own Mathoid server. where to install the server? do I need a new server to host mathoid? can anyone explain to me how to install mathoid server?

The article on mathoid https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Mathoid is confusing.

Comment: What's the problem with `mathoid-beta.wmflabs.org`? It seems operational.

Comment: Test Rendering Presentation MathML sample failed, Test Checking if the link to SVG image is correct failed. Is there any way to write math equations on mediawiki?